# Can I add Runtime Properties to a Python App Engine App?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, properties, runtime

Coming from a java background I'm used to having a bunch of properties files I can swap round at runtime dependent on what server I'm running on e.g. dev/production.

Is there a method in python to do similar, specifically on Google's App Engine framework?

At the minute I have them defined in .py files, obviously I'd like a better separation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

1. edit records in the datastore through the dashboard ( if you really have to )
2. upload new scripts / files  ( you can access files in READ-ONLY )
3. export a WEB Service API to configuration records in the datastore ( probably not what you had in mind )
4. access a page somewhere through an HTTP end-point

Comment: through the usual Python file I/O: use relative paths of course e.g. get current directory.

Comment: is that guaranteed to work in a distributed environment such as app engine?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see what is wrong with using python files to configure your application (apart from cultural issues :) ).  In fact I have an issue with frameworks which *don't* allow me to script the configuration parameters.

That said, please have a look http://aaron.oirt.rutgers.edu/myapp/docs/W1100_2300.GAEDeploy for
a discussion of how to configure WHIFF application resources to configure applications to work in and out of the GAE framework in a portable manner.

Comment: I guess it is a culture thing.  Just the fact that a .py file can do more, whereas .properties is somewhat foolproof (I like foolproof)

Comment: I don't think .properties files are foolproof (I must be a bigger fool than you).

Comment: If you want a powerful analogue to .properties for loading data into Python you could use files in JSON format...  I still like to be able to do things like "for" loops and math computations in my configuration file however.